# How can I run my Timer forever in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net

In ASP.NET I want to run my timer forever (as long as my host server is running). How can I achieve this?

```
public int ClickCount
{
        get
        {
            object o = ViewState["ClickCount"];
            return (o == null) ? 0 : (int)o;
        }
        set
        {
            ViewState["ClickCount"] = value;
        }
    }

    public int minute
    {
        get
        {
            object o = ViewState["minute"];
            return (o == null) ? 0 : (int)o;
        }
        set
        {
            ViewState["minute"] = value;
        }
    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (minute < 5)
        {
            if (ClickCount < 5)
            {
                ClickCount++;
                MsgBox("node inserted", this.Page, this);
            }
            else
            {
                MsgBox("not more than 5 nodes in 5 minutes", this.Page, 
this);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            minute = 0;
            ClickCount = 0;
        }
    }

    protected void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        minute = minute + 1;
    }

<asp:Timer ID="Timer1" runat="server" Interval="60000" 
           ontick="Timer1_Tick">
</asp:Timer>
```

According to me my variable "minute" well be incremented by 1 after every timer_tick event. But problem is that my timer will be close when i stop my application. And as you says that I can use host server system clock, then how can I use it. I mean to say that how I can code my application so that at every host server system clock pulse my variable "minute" will be incremented by 1. Thanks.

Comment: Your server already has a timer that runs forever. It’s called the system clock. Can you explain why that does not meet your needs?

Comment: how can i increament variable "minute" by 1 after every minute using server timer

Comment: You don't need to update a (user specific) ViewState value every minute, you just need to know the difference between the start time and the current time, in minutes. And that start time needs to be stored in a user-specific way

Answer (score 2):

To start your "timer," store the current time.

```
void StartTimer()
{
    ViewState["StartTime"] = DateTime.Now;
}
```

When you wish to obtain a value for `minutes`, calculate it:

```
int Minutes 
{
    get
    {
        DateTime startTime = (DateTime)ViewState["StartTime"];
        TimeSpan elapsed = DateTime.Now - startTime;
        return elapsed.TotallMinutes;
    }
}
```

There is no need to actually increment anything, or keep a timer of your own.

You could also render the `startTime` value into a hidden HTML field, which would allow Javascript to display the timer by performing a similar calculation. The advantage of JS would be continuous updating.

Comment: Please guide me what would be the coding of JavaScript. I don't know much about JavaScript.

Comment: But i want to calculate the time when my application is not in running stage also. How will server keep the record of it.

Comment: Just like many softwares keep an account of expiry date of their licences.

Comment: Now you’re not making any sense. You want your application to calculate something when it’s not even running? what is this calculation supposed to do?